# I don't understand the figure output from package lme4 in R using the effects library?

Tags: r, data-visualization, interaction, lme4-nlme

I am using **linear-mixed effect models** to analyse my data (the interaction between `on` and `arc`; both `arc` and `on` are continuous variables). I also used the `effects` library to plot the interaction of `on*arc`. However, I could not understand the figure:

[image]

Could you please help in understanding what the 5 panels in the figure represent? Do they represent **quantiles** (e.g., the first 20% lowest arc)?

Why there are **five panels** instead of say **four panels**? I understand that grey band represent the 95% **confidence intervals**, and that orange bars represent ranges of arc (high arc to low arc).

I also wanted to check whether the location of the orange bars represent where the quantiles fall in arc.

Comment: The [help file](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/effects/effects.pdf) of the package `effects` states (page 8) that for continuous covariates, the values are determined by `grid.pretty`. Alternatively, you can set the levels of `arc` manually using the argument `xlevels`. For example: If you want the effect plots for the quantiles of `arc`, you could use the option `xlevels=list(arc=quantile(mydata$arc, seq(0, 1, 0.25)))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have an interaction, the relationship between, say, `on` and `ff` depends on the value of `arc`.  This is hard for many people to understand and it can be a challenge to visualize.  What the effects package has done for you is make a [coplot](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2428-when-and-how-to-use-conditional-plots-co-plots-for-data-analysis/) (sometimes called a conditioning plot).  It is showing you the predicted relationship (with what I'm guessing is a 95% confidence band) at five different points in `arc`.  The orange bars represent the locations in `arc` where the relationship is plotted; they are not ranges.  Specifically, the relationship between `on` adn `ff` seems to be plotted when `arc` is equal to $0$, $2$, $4$, $6$, and $8$.  It could show you the relationship at **4** different point in `arc`, and probably would with some appropriate fiddling with the function call.